# Create pie chart from an Application Report?

Tags: excel, pie-chart

I have several mac users who claim they need all 3 major browsers for testing websites and they need Admin privileges to keep them updated. (My Company doesn't support but Safari.)

I have run an Application Usage report for the last year on these users to pull what applications where used, how long, etc etc..

I have the data in Excel and I am trying to 'pie' chart the data so I can see what application they are really using the most. I have already split each user up into individual sheets. Has anyone else encountered this? I'm not an Excel guru. Is this question even relevant to this exchange?

[image]

Comment: I guess what I am trying to get is for Excel to spit out: This user uses Firefox 95%, Safari 3% Firefox 2%.

Answer (score 0):

Your data would need to show the relevant browser but since you would like % then a pie chart from a PivotTable is probably easiest:

[image: SO17813844 example]

Select your range (`Browser` & `Run Time`), Insert > Tables - PivotTable, PivotTable. Drag "Choose fields to show in report:" as shown, for `Σ values` Summarize value field by Sum and Shows values as % of total. Click on PivotTable and Insert, Charts, Pie, select something suitable, right click on pie and Add Data Labels.